# Does the MLB website contain win-loss stats? If so, how can I examine win-loss stats on the MLB website?

Tags: baseball, statistics, mlb

I am looking for win and loss stats on the [MLB website](https://www.mlb.com/).

I've browsed to the MLB website > Stats > Team, but I did not find win-loss stats. What am I missing?

[image: statistics page]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to click on the "standings" tab:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

> I am look[ing] for win and loss stats on [the] MLB website.

As [already noted](https://sports.stackexchange.com/a/22459), click the "Standings" tab.

This contains win and loss statistics for every team for every date during a given season. You can also toggle between the wild card race, spring training standings, postseason projections (later in the season), division/league/MLB and standard/advanced.

[image: mlb standings]

Note: Some functionality does not work the further you go back as some features were not tracked at one time.